# Desktop applications for uploading files to SP 2013 and adding Metadata?

Tags: file-upload

Are there desktop client applications from Microsoft for `MS Windows 7` which allow the user to

- upload files in SharePoint 2013
- add/modify their Metadata?

Comment: Is it SharePoint 2010 or 2013? If 2010 - there's SharePoint 2010 Workspaces/Groove that allows you sync your SharePoint lists and libraries for offline use - I think it should (as I didn't really use it) allow you to upload files as well. => [SharePoint Workspace 2010 overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649102(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

i think what your looking for is here:

**Document Importer For SharePoint**

> (Free / File Import / Bulk Import For SharePoint / Office 365 /
>   SharePoint Online / 2010 / 2013 / Server / Foundation )
>
> Quickly import large volumes of documents into SharePoint document
>   libraries using an effective user interface.
>
> The application uses the client object model of SharePoint which you
>   install separately from here if you want to run the application on a
>   machine that is not a SharePoint server.

https://difs.codeplex.com/

its a nice app that uses csom on client side to upload documents to a sharepoint library! if you want somthing else than that would mean making a custom desktop application unfortunatly!

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! In fact, I heard about something called like `Microsoft OneDrive` or similar, a Windows Desktop application which could connect to SharePoint...

Comment: It looked very promising, but it produces a lot of error messages and some confusion at first sight.. :-( Do you have any experience with this tool and SharePoint 2013 yourself?

Comment: what error are you getting? some reported that it throws error but still uploads the document!

Comment: in fact, it uploaded most of the documents, but not all. I'll have to check in detail. There were a lot of errors about the uploaded files being checked out by me (which is ok from my point of view). The main problem: creation and modified date were not preserved (although the setting was checked in the import options).

Comment: DIFS.Codeplex.Com has been updated and now does automatically maintain the file uploaded date.

Answer (score 0):

Same question here;
So far, I have looked at
- MS SharePoint Workspace: discontinued
- Colligo Briefcase (now part of the Engage suite of applications). Impressive as far as functionality and stability is concerned, but unfortunately they discontinued their software development kit. Yet, they are willing to add functionality if they find your requirement can benefit more clients. 
- Neoxen Visual Explorer: similar to Colligo Briefcase, very good, but they too discontinued their SDK. Moreover, it takes them weeks, and reminders to respond, if at all.
- Knowledgelake Connect: still waiting for a demo version
I would not mind keeping you informed of my findings through this channel, if you are interested.

Answer (score -1):

KnowledgeLake has an application called Connect. It is a nice product if you have a SharePoint ECM solution and would prefer that users not work directly with the SharePoint UI. 
- End-users can upload, search, find and interact with content from multiple SharePoint environments (2007, 2010, 2013, Cloud/Office365) in a single, consolidated view (desktop application)
- Automatic indexing and data validation 
You can find more information about the product here:
https://www.knowledgelake.com/knowledgelake-connect-sharepoint-client-desktop-microsoft-office-integration

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)